# Compare & manipulate strings with python

Tags: python

I've written an [XML parser](http://pastebin.com/D9DkQdEv) in Python and have just [added functionality](http://pastebin.com/Y0DjtwHu) to read a further script from a different directory.

I've got two args, first is the path where I'm parsing XML. Second is a string in another XML file which I want to match with the first path;

`arg1 = \work\parser\main\tools\app\shared\xml\calculators\2012\example\calculator`
`path = calculators/2012/example/calculator`

How can I compare the two strings to match identify that they're both referencing the same thing and also, how can I strip `calculator` from either string so I can store that & use it?

*edit*

Just had a thought. I have used a Regex to get the year out of the path already with `year = re.findall(r"\.(\d{4})\.", path)` following a problem Python has with numbers when converting the path to an import statement.

I could obviously split the strings and use a regex to match the path as a pattern in arg1 but this seems a long way round. Surely there's a better method?

Comment: It'd be helpful if down-votes came with some feedback so I could at least learn something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here I am assuming you are actually talking about strings, and not file paths - for which @mgilson's suggestion is better*

> How can I compare the two strings to match identify that they're both
>   referencing the same thing

Well first you need to identify what you mean by *"the same thing"*

At first glance it seems that if the the second string ends with the first string with the reversed slash, you have a match.

```
arg1 = r'\work\parser\main\tools\app\shared\xml\calculators\2012\example\calculator'
arg2 = r'calculators/2012/example/calculator'

>>> arg1.endswith(arg2.replace('/','\\'))
True
```

> and also, how can I strip calculator from
>   either string so I can store that & use it?

You also need to decide if you want to strip the first *calculator*, the last *calculator* or any occurance of *calculator* in the string.

If you just want to remove the last string after the separator, then its simply:

```
>>> arg2.split('/')[-1]
'calculator'
```

Now to get the orignal string back, without the last bit:

```
>>> '/'.join(arg2.split('/')[:-1])
'calculators/2012/example'
```

Comment: Now thats where 'calculator' becomes a bad example actually. It's the last instance in the string and probably wont ever be called 'calculator' in practise. Thats very helpful though. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

check out `os.path.samefile`:

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile

and `os.path.dirname`:

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname

or maybe `os.path.basename` (I'm not sure what part of the string you want to keep).

Comment: thanks. I was looking at string operations like substring etc so I'll give those a read :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
arg1 = "\work\parser\main\tools\app\shared\xml\calculators\2012\example\calculator"
path = "calculators/2012/example/calculator"

arg1=arg1.replace("/","\\")
path=path.replace("/","\\")
if str(arg1).endswith(str(path)) or str(path).endswith(str(arg1)):
    print "Match"
```

That should work for your needs. Cheers :)